# how can I make an internal API design where only react app can listen to `internal_api`?

Tags: reactjs, django, docker, docker-compose

I want to perform (get, post) operations to `internal API` without exposing the API to the world since it's just for creating new subscribers, managing the landing page, sending emails and mostly `create, update, delete` operations for administrators that I don't want to be publicly available `/api/v1/`?

````
version: '3.7'
services:
  internal_api:
    build:
      context: ./backend/services/internal_api
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: internal_api
    command: gunicorn internal_api.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 -w 2
    volumes:
      - static_app:/home/app/app/static
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    env_file:
      - ./devops/.env.internal_api.prod
    depends_on:
      - database_01
  landing:
    build:
      context: ./frontend/landing
    container_name: landing
    volumes:
      - ./frontend/landing:/usr/src/app
networks:
  external_network:
  internal_network:
    internal: true```
````

Comment: How do you know someone is an "administrator" and should have access to this page?  (This probably can't be solved in pure Docker constructs since they probably are not running their browser from the same server as the application, so the admin application must be published in some form.)

Answer (score 0):

You could make it so that only clients that know a "secret" value are able to access the API, but since it looks like your client is written in React, then it would be possible for a determined attacker to inspect your code and find your token.

Any API calls that React is going to make are going to be made over HTTPS, so in theory any client would be able to "pretend" they are your client.